# Nuxt 3 how to use dynamic variable for img src

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

So I'm trying to get an img url from an object and setting is as img src. But it's not working and I do not know why.

My variable looks like this:

```
const props = defineProps({
  about: {
    title: String,
    text: String,
    img: String,
    leftSide: Boolean
  }
})

const cardImg = '~assets/images/' + props.about.img // prints ~assets/images/image.png
```

this is what i've tried:

```
<img :src="cardImg" />
```

And I've tried to use require() as well:

```
<img :src="require(cardImg)" />
```

But when I use require() I am getting this error:

```
Cannot find module '~assets/images/image.png' Require stack: -
```

The only way I can set an img src is like this:

```
<img src="~assets/images/image.png" />
```

But I want the src to be a variable so its dynamic, do you guys know what I am doing wrong

this is the parent component

```
<section v-for="info in aboutInfo">
   <about-card :about="info"></about-card>
</section>

<script setup>

const aboutInfo = [
{
      title: "some title",
      text: "some text",
      img: "image.png",
      leftSide: true
    }
]
</script>
```

Comment: I believe your issue is within the lifecycle of your prop, but I am not positive. What does the parent component look like?

Comment: @Kyrony i've updated it

Comment: `require()` doesn't work with dynamic assets. When you app gets built for production, it simply goes through all known usages and adds each of them to the bundle. If you need to work with dynamic assets, the only option is to put them into `/public/` folder, which gets added *"as is"* to the bundle. As shown in Mises's answer. Or you could make a mapper which lists all possible images and runs them through `require()`, in which case they'll all be processed.

Answer (score 4):

Assets folder is for files that can marge with bundle files like CSS, JS. svg. For images, use folder `public`. If you create folder images there, just use path `/images/image.png` without `/public/` prefix.

```html
<img :src="'/images/image.png'" />
```

Comment: how come on nuxt docs:  <img src="~/assets/img/nuxt.png" alt="Discover Nuxt 3" /> how to get dynamic images to work with vite?

Answer (score -2):

You should do like this:

```
<template>
  <img :src="ImageSrc" />
</template>

<script setup>
  const ImageSrc= "/_nuxt/assets/images.image.png"
</script>
```

Comment: This will break on production build

Comment: Don't put images in an asset's folder. Assets folder is for files nuxt3 can consume like JavaScript files or SVG/CSS files or JSON files, not images.